# How to query and update a Data Extension from an external site using JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, jquery, ajax

I'm putting together an email preferences form and what I want to do is retrieve existing preferences if a record with the specified email exists and add/update a record with the customer's details on submission.

I have the existing/previous page to use a reference. Unfortunately it's completely undocumented, but as best I can tell it's submitting JSON data to a specific URL using ajax. The main thing I'm unsure of is where/how this URL is determined (I presume it's specific to the Data Extension in question) and where this functionality is documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below API to retrieve the data from data extension
***https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[DE CustomerKey]/rowset/***

To insert the data you can follow the below link

***https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.htm***

Comment: REST API is not able to retrieve data. This can only be done in SOAP.

Comment: I think we can get DE using the rest API because I've tried with the same approach as **Advait** mentioned. We can do either by using soap API or rest API. 
  
 **@Lukas Lunow could please explain why we can't retrieve the data using rest API?**